# How many instances of a letter appear in a dictionary

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this question where it takes a dictionary and tries to find each instance of a letter if it exists and prints it so

```
 get_letter_frequency('all animals are equal but some animals are more equal than others')
```

would print:

```
a appears 10 times
b appears 1 time
e appears 7 times
h appears 2 times
i appears 2 times
l appears 6 times
m appears 4 times
n appears 3 times
o appears 3 times
q appears 2 times
r appears 4 times
s appears 4 times
t appears 3 times
u appears 3 times
```

I have this so far for my get_letter_frequency function

```
def get_letter_frequency(a_string):
    dictionary = {}
    words = a_string.split()
    for letters in words:
      if letters != " ":
          if letters in dictionary:
              dictionary[letters] += 1
          else:
              dictionary[letters] = 1
      dictionary_keys = dictionary.keys()
      new_list = list(dictionary_keys)
      new_list.sort()
      for alphabet in new_list:
          if dictionary[alphabet] == 1:
              print(alphabet, "appears", dictionary[alphabet], "time")
          else:
              print(alphabet, "appears", dictionary[alphabet], "times")
```

But this instead gives me all the letters in the dictionary and tells me how many times it appear.

```
all appears 1 time
animals appears 2 times
are appears 2 times
but appears 1 time
equal appears 2 times
more appears 1 time
others appears 1 time
some appears 1 time
than appears 1 time
```

Can you please help. Thank you.

Comment: actually when i tried in python2 i got the result you are expecting but as you have tried in python 3 try replacing `words = a_string.split()` by `words = a_string.split(" ")`

Comment: `def letter_freq(s):return Counter(c for c in s.lower() if c.isalpha())`. Making all same case otherwise upper and lower counted separately. Filtered out all non-letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in these lines:

```
words = a_string.split()
for letters in words:
```

You are expecting it to iterate all the letters in `words`, but it actually traverses individual words. In Python, you can use strings as if they are `list`s of characters, so changing your `for line to the following will work:

```
for letters in a_string:
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand.

Answer (score 3):

The issue in the code is:

```
for letters in words:
```

Since `words` is a list of words, the variable `letters` will contain each of those words in turn, not the letters from those words.

The Counter class from the collections module does what you need:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: ctr = Counter('all animals are equal but some animals are more equal than others')

In [3]: list(ctr)
Out[3]: ['a', ' ', 'b', 'e', 'i', 'h', 'm', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'q', 's', 'r', 'u', 't']

In [4]: dict(ctr)
Out[4]: 
{' ': 11,
 'a': 10,
 'b': 1,
 'e': 7,
 'h': 2,
 'i': 2,
 'l': 6,
 'm': 4,
 'n': 3,
 'o': 3,
 'q': 2,
 'r': 4,
 's': 4,
 't': 3,
 'u': 3}
```

#### Without using the collections module

If you must do this with `for` loops and no modules:

```
def get_letter_frequency(a_string):
    dictionary = {}
    for letter in a_string.replace(' ', ''):
        dictionary[letter] = dictionary.get(letter, 0) + 1
    for letter in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
        print(letter, "appears", dictionary[letter], ["time", "times"][dictionary[letter]>1])
```

For example:

```
>>> get_letter_frequency('all animals are equal but some animals are more equal than others')
a appears 10 times
b appears 1 time
e appears 7 times
h appears 2 times
i appears 2 times
l appears 6 times
m appears 4 times
n appears 3 times
o appears 3 times
q appears 2 times
r appears 4 times
s appears 4 times
t appears 3 times
u appears 3 times
```

Comment: I can't use the collections module.

Comment: @R.Mercy OK.  I added a solution that uses only basic python.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue using `collections.Counter` gives you the most elegant solution, but if you prefer to use your own function try

```
letters = list(a_string)
```

instead of `str.split()`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the string as such(taking from your example)

```
statement = 'all animals are equal but some animals are more equal than others'
characters = list(statement)

then

from collections import Counter

Counter(characters)

Output:

Counter({'a': 10,
         'b': 1,
         'e': 7,
         'h': 2,
         'i': 2,
         'l': 6,
         'm': 4,
         'n': 3,
         'o': 3,
         'q': 2,
         'r': 4,
         's': 4,
         't': 3,
         'u': 3})
```

It seems like all the answers are more or less on same lines :D

Answer (score 0):

The standard library provides for such counters:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = "apple banana apple strawberry banana lemon cupcake battery staple"
>>> Counter(words)
Counter({' ': 8,
         'a': 12,
         'b': 4,
         'c': 2,
         'e': 7,
         'k': 1,
         'l': 4,
         'm': 1,
         'n': 5,
         'o': 1,
         'p': 6,
         'r': 4,
         's': 2,
         't': 4,
         'u': 1,
         'w': 1,
         'y': 2})
```

Comment: I need to use an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

`words = a_string.split()` splits the string into a list of words. You then loop through all those words instead of the letters. Since you don't seem to care for spaces `" "` you could replace that by

```
no_whitespace_str = a_string.replace(" ", "")
for letters in no_whitespace_str:
    ...
```

A shorter version would be

```
def get_letter_frequency(str):
    occ = {v: str.count(v) for v in str.replace(" ","")}
    for letter, num in sorted(occ.iteritems()):
        print "{} appears {} times".format(letter, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sent = "all animals are equal but some animals are more equal than others"
dic = {}

for ele in sent:
    dic.setdefault(ele,0) += 1
```

This gives dic as using (`print dic`)

`{'a': 10, ' ': 11, 'b': 1, 'e': 7, 'i': 2, 'h': 2, 'm': 4, 'l': 6, 'o': 3, 'n': 3, 'q': 2, 's': 4, 'r': 4, 'u': 3, 't': 3}`

In python `string` is a `list` so you can iterate over individual characters in a string